# How do i post something in the page console using "Puppeteer "

Tags: javascript, discord.js, puppeteer

Hey guys I'm creating an Automated script which his job is to put something in the page console with
puppeteer i wanna it to write in the page console:

```js
function login(token) {
setInterval(() => {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
location.reload();
}, 2500);
}
```

and write this too after the first one:

```
login("Token")
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`?

Comment: dude `console.log` will appear in my cmd not in the page

Comment: "I want it to write in the console" - sounded like what you were asking. It will also write to the devtools Console if that's of any use. But regardless, what's wrong with the code you provided? What is the behavior, are there any errors, etc? You haven't actually *asked a question*.

Comment: sorry i mean in page console